# How do I use variables in SQL Server backup disk path?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The following SQL statement works fine:

```
DECLARE @database VARCHAR(30) = 'DEMO';

BACKUP LOG @database
TO DISK = N'C:\zbackups\DEMO.trn' 
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  
NAME = N'MyDatabase Log Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10;

DBCC SHRINKFILE ('DEMO_log', 500);
```

This however does not:

```
DECLARE @database VARCHAR(30) = 'DEMO';

BACKUP LOG @database
TO DISK = 'C:\zbackups\' + @database + '.trn' 
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  
NAME = 'MyDatabase Log Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10;

DBCC SHRINKFILE (@database + '_log', 500);
```

Both the `TO DISK` directive and the `DBCC SHRINKFILE` parameters throw an error when I attempt to concatenate.

How do I use a variable in these location? Would also like to append some datetime parameters to the file path but haven't started researching that yet.

Comment: Side note: SQL Server 2008 has been *completely* unsupported for 3 years; it is long past time you sorted out your upgrade path.

Comment: If you are developing maintenance scripts for your servers, I would advise heading on over to https://ola.hallengren.com/.

Comment: A reality check for the shrink is to compare the log file size to the size of the data files.  A 10 MB data file and a 35 GB log file calls for a shrink to fix years of a missing transaction log backup.  If the log size is at it's "stable" growth limit, it would be a waste resources to shrink it.

Comment: Also why NOINIT? Do you not care if the .trn file eventually contains 50,000 log backups and grows to 5 TB in size? Do you only care about the last log backup anyway? It seems not, this cycle seems to be optimized simply to allow you to shrink. In which case maybe you just shouldn't be in full recovery. See the cleverly-placed links in my answer for more info.

Comment: @Larnu Agreed. Our upgrade path is in place and mostly waiting on... leadership, to **buy** in.

Comment: @RandyinMarin 30-80 GB log files on dozens of databases. I found out the DBA is bypassing sql server when taking the backups so the log files have grown out of control. Trying to learn enough to clean up the mess and keep it cleaned up until upgrade.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I don't actually know what no-init does but do not care if the log file appends. Most likely by the time the file is finished writing it will be whisked away to an archive by another script.

Comment: @danielson317 Again, you don't need to do this.  Ola's script is easy to install.  It will even create the jobs for you.  (It won't schedule the jobs.)  Even if you don't elect to install the jobs, you can use a stored procedure to create the backup.  It will handle timestamps and cleanup if desired.  I've used it for about 15 years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is simply that you can't pass an *expression* there. Instead of:

```
TO  DISK = 'C:\zbackups\' + @database + '.trn'
```

You need:

```
DECLARE @fullpath nvarchar(1024);
SET @fullpath = 'C:\zbackups\' + @database + '.trn';

...

TO DISK = @fullpath

...
```

You can also parameterize the backup name and log file name in a similar way (instead of hard-coding `NAME = 'MyDatabase Log Backup'`). But to get the shrink operation to run in the right context (if you [really](https://sqlblog.org/2009/07/27/oh-the-horror-please-stop-telling-people-they-should-shrink-their-log-files), [really](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/), [really](https://am2.co/should-i-shrink-my-database/), [really](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/29829/1186) need it, that is), and you can rely on every single database being configured in the same way, you're going to have to hard-code the database name somewhere (e.g. in a `USE` statement), or use dynamic SQL to set the context to the right database, e.g.

```
DECLARE @database sysname = N'DEMO';

DECLARE @fullpath    nvarchar(1024) = N'C:\zbackups\' + @database + '.trn',
        @backup_name nvarchar(500)  = @database + N' log backup',
        @log_name    nvarchar(500)  = @database _ N'_log';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'BACKUP LOG @db
  TO DISK = @fullpath
  WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = @backup_name, 
  SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10;

DBCC SHRINKFILE(@log, 500);';

DECLARE @context nvarchar(1024) = QUOTENAME(@database)
  + N'.sys.sp_executesql';

EXECUTE @context @sql, -- run @sql but in the context of @database
  N'@db sysname, @log nvarchar(500), 
    @fullpath nvarchar(1024), @backup_name nvarchar(500)',
    @database, @log_name, @fullpath, @backup_name;
```

Answer (score 3):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 a variable can be used.  I think an expression would be listed if allowed.  The same goes for DBCC SHRINKFILE.  Try

```
DECLARE @database VARCHAR(30) = 'DEMO';
DECLARE @target VARCHAR(260) = 'C:\zbackups\' + @database + '.trn';
DECLARE @logical_name VARCHAR(128) = @database + '_log';

BACKUP LOG @database
TO  DISK = @target
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  
NAME = 'MyDatabase Log Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10;

DBCC SHRINKFILE (@logical_name, 500);
```

If the logical file name does not always follow the dbname_log pattern, perhaps lookup the file id and use that instead of the logical name in SHRINKFILE.  Be careful of database scope on the connection.

```
DECLARE @file_id int

SELECT @file_id = file_id 
FROM sys.database_files
WHERE physical_name = @target
```