SSIS Execute SQL Task Variable Substitution Issue
I have the following SQL Statement in a SSIS Execute SQL Task:
        use [master];
        declare @DatabaseBackupPath varchar(250) = ?;
        
        backup database [DW]
        to  disk = @DatabaseBackupPath
        with copy_only
           , noformat
           , init
           , name = N'DW-Full Database Backup'
           , skip
           , norewind
           , nounload
           , compression
           , stats = 10;
        go

Variables are configured correctly and if value is e.g. set to 'C:\DEV\DW.bak', I get the error below when I run the task (i.e. backup path is being prefixed with C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\BACKUP):

Error: Cannot open backup device 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\BACKUP\'C:\DEV\DW.bak''. Operating system error 123(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.).

Our workload requires database to be restored in the event of a failure in the process and the Backup Database task is not suitable for us as it adds a timestamp to the database backup name. Any help with above error would be much appreciated.
If I put the query in a variable and then reference this in the execute SQL Task, it works but just wondered if anyone has encountered above issue before or can explain why it may be happening.

With the minimal details we have, I can't replicate your problem.

What is the actual value in the variable?  Does it have single quotes in it or just the path?
Maybe this could help:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/72943674/1459036

Thank you @ThomA for having a look. Steps to replicate within a SSIS package:

Add a variable - this variable is named DatabaseBackupPath and I have set value to 'C:\DEV\DW.bak' for testing
Add an Execute SQL Task --> Under General, configure connection, SQLSourceType = Direct input, SQLStatement = the backup script in my question above; under Parameter Mapping, add User::DatabaseBackupPath

Does above help?
